# Configuration HSQLDB big storage

Tags: hsqldb

First, sorry for my approximative english.

I'm a little lost with HSQLDB using.
I need to save in local database a big size of data (3Go+), in a minimum of time.

So I made the following :

- CREATE CACHED TABLE ...; for save data in .data file
- SET FILES LOG FALSE; for don't save data in .log file and gain time
- SHUTDOWN COMPACT; for save records in local disk

I know there's other variable to parameter for increase the .data size and for increase data access speed, like :

- hsqldb.cache_scale=
- hsqldb.cache_size_scale=
- SET FILES NIO SIZE xxxx

But I don't know how to parameter this for a big storage.

Thanks to help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `SET FILES LOG FALSE` data changes are not saved until you execute `SHUTDOWN` 
or `CHECKPOINT`.

The other parameters can be left to their default values. If you want to use more memory and gain some speed, you can multiply the default values of the parameters by 2 or 4.